# Jquery Toggle with Multiple Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I have two images with different IDs, lets say #pic1 and #pic2. I tried adding both selectors to a toggle but they both toggle the same element independently, so when you click the first pic and then the second, the second doesn't toggle the target div back it performs the first part of the toggle a second time. For instance if it's supposed to slide a 100px to the left and then slide 100px back to the right, clicking #pic1 would slide it 100px left but clicking #pic2 would just slide it 100px to the left again. Can someone give me an idea of what direction I should be looking?

```
$('#pic1,#pic2').toggle(
function()
{
  $('#mylayer').delay(1000).animate({left: "+=100"});
  $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 0.8});
},
function()
{
  $('#mylayer').animate({left: "-=100"});
  $('#overlay').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0});
});
```

Comment: this is, because the toggle-in and toggle-out functions are always assigned to each toggeling element seperately. Toggle() doesn't seem to be appropriate for your useCase.

Comment: Add a class to both and use that as a selector instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this that keeps track of the open/closed state once for both clicks and uses jQuery's data capability to avoid using a global variable and to make this more extensible to be used multiple places:

```
$('#pic1,#pic2').click() {
    var mylayer = $("#mylayer");
    var open = mylayer.data("open");
    if (open) {
        mylayer.animate({left: "-=100"});
        $('#overlay').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0});
        mylayer.data("open", false);
    } else {
        mylayer.delay(1000).animate({left: "+=100"});
        $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 0.8});
        mylayer.data("open", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You!!! I had to make a few adjustments but this is just what I needed. I had done something like this before by binding an unbinding click handlers but it was clunky and this is excellent and lightweight!